# How can I automate interacting with Github API via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, github, github-api, invoke-webrequest

(originally asked "How can I use SSH pub/priv keys to authenticate via Invoke-WebRequest?")

I wanted to automate some housekeeping of my github repos, and (at least for learning) I thought I'd do it with Powershell. Is there a way to provide SSH private/public key pair to the Get-Credential (so I could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951561/use-invoke-webrequest-with-a-username-and-password-for-basic-authentication-on-t)), or straight to the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet, to automate stuff authenticating to the Github API?

Or am I going the hard way and there is an easier way to do this (staying on the course of using the SSH keys)?

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` is for HTTP. SSH keys are not used with HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as Martin pointed out in the comments:

> `Invoke-WebRequest` is for HTTP. SSH keys are not used with HTTP.

I was truly and honestly ignorant to that "detail" and thought it could be done.

After being pointed that, I've found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370829/using-ssh-keys-for-http-user-verification), and with some more digging, I've found out that what I really need are [developer tokens](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).